# Is there a way to find out what winform/wpf components a program uses?

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio

I'm a complete novice in gui-programming and I'm looking for an easy way to visualize a data structure I have. I own another program that does a similar job and the component it uses seems like it would fulfill my purposes as well. So instead of testing out different components myself (Which would undoubtedly force me to learn a lot), I'm wondering if there's a fast way out of it.

Is there anyway to find out what specific wpf/winform component a program is using without asking author/having source code access?

Edit:
Looks like this, the area it's in is scrollable horizontally/vertically. The objects on it are selectable, moveable and have actions associated with their right-click menu. I want to visualize an undirected graph and have the possibility to interact with the nodes graphically.

Here's the control I'm talking about:

[image: weird object graph control thingie]

Comment: Erm, a quicker way would be to post a screenshot and let us tell you. If it's a standard control, there's a good chance someone will recognize it instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, I'd look at the assemblies the app references. If it references a dll from a component vendor (a simple search can figure this out), you can visit the vendor's website and check out their offerings.

If it is a custom control embedded within the application, and its a WPF app, I'd use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

[image: image of Snoop UI]

(Image ganked from http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).  Snoop can sniff out the visual tree of a WPF application at runtime and show you all the controls that make it up.

Comment: Accepting your answer since it seem to answer the general question on how to find out the forms in a WPF program. Unfortuntely the progrem in question was not, and it seems that the control is some custom form using GDI classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is no standard control but some propritary one. You can have a look in the program folder of that program which dll's they use, chances are that you can use this dll in your own app. Note that the license of this application may forbid using the code!